# Dúvida sobre variáveis globais do PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Até agora eu não sei como funciona as variáveis: **$_SESSION,**    **$_POST,** e **$_GET**, alguém poderia me explicar como funciona? Valeu!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

São variáiveis superglobais do PHP, em que está disponível em todos os Escopos do script

$_SESSION é uma array que armazena todas as informações da sessão do usuário, dura por padrão 14 minutos todas as informações na variável.

$_POST é uma array que armazena todos os parâmetros do tipo POST da requisição.

$_GET é uma array que armazena todos os parâmetros do tipo GET da requisição

Todas são uma 'superglobal', ou variável global automática. Isto significa que ela está disponível em todos escopos pelo script. Não há necessidade de fazer global $variable; para acessá-la dentro de uma função ou método.

Mais informações:
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php
https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.post.php